# Weird results from multiplying uint16_t variable with a number

Tags: c

I have a very simple piece of C code that gives me weird result. I'm developing a simple wireless sensor network application for Micaz motes. It seems to have ATmega128L 8 bit AVR microprocessors. I'm using AVR studio to write and compile the code.

```
uint16_t myvariable;
uint16_t myresult;
myresult = myvariable*256;
```

When myvariable is 3, I found myresult was always reset to 512. Just wondering why it works like this. My guess is, the mixture of such a literal number 256 and uint16_t magically causes the problem. But I don't know why. Could anybody give a detailed explanation on this? Appreciate for any help!

More detailed source code is as follows.

```
static uint16_t myvariable[2];
static uint8_t AckMsg[32];
uint16_t myresult[MAX_SENDERS];

void protocol()  
{           
    if(thisnodeid != 5){   // sender nodes
      while (1)
      {         
        if(AckReceived && !MsgSent) {
          // If ACK received and a new message not sent yet,
          // send a new message on sending node.
        }

        else if(!AckReceived && MsgSent)
        {
            lib_radio_receive_timed(16, 32, AckMsg, 120);
            myvariable[0] = AckMsg[0];
            myvariable[1] = AckMsg[1];
            // Bug!!!, variable overflowed.
            myresult[thisnodeid] = 256*myvariable[1] + myvariable[0];  
        }

      }
    }           

}
```

What I really want to figure out is, how the compiler compiles following line of code, because I know it's this line of code causes the bug. Thanks in advance for any information!

```
myresult[thisnodeid] = 256*myvariable[1] + myvariable[0];
```

When myvariable[1]=3, myvariable[0]=0, I always get myresult[] = 512. Looks 768 is always reset to 512. Just don't know why.

Comment: The compiler interprets literal number values as int, what compiler are you using and what microprocessor?

Comment: Can you post the exact source code that demonstrates the problem, including the assignment to `myvariable` and the code to print `myresult`?

Comment: @JesusRamos: Not necessarily.  If the literal doesn't fit in an `int`, then it tries `long`, and so on...

Comment: Please tell me more about this magical processor that can represent 256 as an 8-bit value.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth True, what I meant was the smallest a literal can be is an int unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Yeah, you need to give all the details about your platform, development environment, and code in order for us to help you on this.

Comment: I'm using Micaz motes. I looks like it's an ATmega128L AVR microprocessor in it.

Comment: @StephenCanon: That's only true for oct/hex...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: ah, right you are.

Comment: @StephenCanon: To elaborate on what Oli said, all decimal integer constants are signed unless they have the `U` suffix. The "try `unsigned int`" etc. steps only happen for hex or octal constants.

Comment: It's not impossible this is a compiler bug (microcontroller compilers are often less robust than you might hope).  Can you post a short, complete program that demonstrates the issue, and also the corresponding assembler code output by the compiler?

Comment: Just updated the question with actual source code.

Comment: @kevinlu: Can you make that any shorter (ideally 20 lines or less)?  It's entirely possible that you're causing undefined behaviour somewhere else in your code that's inadvertently causing the side-effect that you're observing.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Just updated the source code.

Comment: Your description refers to `myvariable` and `myresult`, which do not appear in your source code. Your source code doesn't show the declarations of most of the identifiers it refers to. Can you show us a small self-contained example, along with the output it produces vs. what you expected?

Comment: And what are the values of `myvariable[1]` and `myvariable[0]` when the overflow occurs? Is `int` 16 bits on your system? BTW, what I meant by "self-contained" is a small complete program that doesn't depend on any other declarations; you could probably drop most of your code and replace the array elements by single declared variables with known values and still reproduce the problem.

Comment: @kevinlu: Then you have a non-conforming C implementation. Not that that's a crime, but it would have been good to know that. (The C standard requires `int` to be at least 16 bits.) What are the values of `myvariable[1]` and `myvariable[0]` when the overflow occurs?

Comment: @KeithThompson: When myvarialbe[1] exceeds 2, say 3, the overflow occurs. Looks it give result like this 3*256 -> 512. I was thinking myvariable[1]*256 was reset as a 8 bit number, but 2^8 = 256. So I couldn't understand why 3*256 gets reset to 512, but not 256.

Comment: Can you make your compiler output assembly code?  That might help with understanding exactly what is happening at the line in question.

Comment: @kevinlu: What are the values of `myvariable[1]` *and* `myvariable[0]`? You're multiplying two numbers; we need to know both of them to have any clue what's going on. Or, given the values of the two variables, do the calculation yourself by hand; will the result it in a `uint16_t`? Update: Looking more closely at your code, you're not multiplying them together; still, you should examine the values of everything that the calculation depends on.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with something like: `uint16_t x = some_value; uint16_t y = some_value; uint16_t result = 256 * x + y;`?

Comment: Note that int is 16 bit on avr-gcc , not 8 bit

Comment: @KeithThompson: When myvariable[1]=3, myvariable[0]=0, I always get myresult[] = 512. Looks 768 is always reset to 512.

Comment: @kevinlu No, int is 16-bit wide.

Comment: Some more questions: 1. How do you *know* that `myresult[] == 512`? Did you print the value? Examine it in a debugger? 2. Is `int` really 8 bits, or is it 16 bits? 3. Are you going to answer the question I asked in my most recent comment? If you help, don't make us ask for information repeatedly. Help us out, try what we suggest. Show us a [small self-contained program](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Well, this is actually a program I wrote a year ago for a research. Right now the problem is I don't have the experimental setup to go over detailed debugging process any more. All I have is the data I saved from a year ago. the value myresult[] and other variables were saved in my previous trace files that printed all these information using printf API in the wireless sensor network OS.

Comment: OK. I think I was wrong. int should be 16 bit.

Comment: Have you tried substituting ```256``` with ```(uint16_t)256```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code without any problem on a standard system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define MAX_SENDERS 10
static uint16_t myvariable[2];
static uint8_t AckMsg[32];
uint16_t myresult[MAX_SENDERS];
main()
{
    AckMsg[0] = 0;
    AckMsg[1] = 3;
    myvariable[0] = AckMsg[0];
    myvariable[1] = AckMsg[1];
    myresult[0] = 256*myvariable[1] + myvariable[0];  
    printf("%d", (int)myresult[0]);
}
```

So to debug you code, you should try to replace the lines :

```
myvariable[0] = AckMsg[0];
myvariable[1] = AckMsg[1];
// Bug!!!, variable overflowed.
myresult[thisnodeid] = 256*myvariable[1] + myvariable[0];
```

by :

```
uint16_t tmp;
myvariable[0] = AckMsg[0];
myvariable[1] = AckMsg[1];
tmp = 256*myvariable[1] + myvariable[0]; 
myresult[thisnodeid] = 256*myvariable[1] + myvariable[0]; 
printf("%d %d\n", (int)(AckMsg[0]), (int)(AckMsg[1]));
printf("%d %d\n", (int)(thisnodeid), (int)(MAX_SENDERS));
printf("%d %d\n", (int)(myvariable[0]), (int)(myvariable[1]));
printf("%d %d\n", (int)(tmp), (int)(myresult[thisnodeid]));
```

This may bring useful information on the origin of the problem.

If you cannot print something in you debugger, you can try the following thing:

```
uint16_t i = 0;
uint16_t n = 255;
myresult[thisnodeid] += myvariable[1];
while (i != n) {
    myresult[thisnodeid] += myvariable[1];
    i += 1;
}
myresult[thisnodeid] += myvariable[0];
```

It will be slow but it may allow you to detect where the overlow is actually happening, because the only variable that will be greater than 255 is `myresult`.